# Expandable menu & menu items with plus and minus

Tags: android, expandablelistview

The image shows what I want to accomplish.

[image: Image Description]

In my activity, I would like to have an expandablelistview. Which, when clicked on, will show a list of items (the items in the list will be populated from a database table). Next to every item, I would like to display a minus, a plus and a number. Every time the plus is clicked the number will add one on the displaying number or if the minus is clicked the displaying number will be subtracted by one. I believe you get the general idea of how the items and the "+" and "-" will work.

I've viewed this tutorial: [Android Custom View Tutorial (Part 1) – Combining Existing Views](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-1-combining-existing-views/)
Unfortunately, this tutorial only covers the plus and minus part and not the expandable view.

The problem I'm facing is how will I imprint this in Java. I've read that I should combine views, but I'm not exactly sure on how. Am I on the correct path?
(In general: I have the design but don't know how to code it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly you only need to create the expandablelistview and the adapter (see here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1151814/Android-ExpandablelistView-Tutorial-with-Android-C), then inside `getChildView()` inflate the  `R.layout.child_row` that contains your Custom View (or you can create a layout using native Android widgets, as the example below).

```
<!-- child_row.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:text="Menu Item 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_less"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_more"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```